# HTMLUnit: ReferenceError: "$" is not defined

Tags: javascript, java, html, htmlunit, referenceerror

I am trying to login to a website using AjaxForm. I managed to retine the forms and reach the xpath of the desired button though when I call #click I get this error:

```
EcmaError: lineNumber=[193] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[ReferenceError] sourceName=[script in https://test.paypo.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FStart from (177, 32) to (221, 10)]
 message=[ReferenceError: "Paypo" is not defined.
 (script in https://test.paypo.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FStart from (177, 32) to (221, 10)#193)] 
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "Paypo" is not defined. (script in https://test.paypo.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FStart from (177, 32) to (221, 10)#193)
```

I am honestly clueless on how to get around this... important note is that I have no access to the source of the website, the actual website logging works perfectly fine.
I've tried using any kind of BrowserVersion and different HtmlUnit versions...

Current code:

```
                final HtmlPage thePage = ((HtmlPage) page);
                final HtmlButtonInput button = (HtmlButtonInput) thePage.getByXPath("//input[@type='button']").get(0);
                webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(true);
                final HtmlPage newPage = button.click();
```

Error araises when #click is called!

Any clue? Please!

Comment: also, i've tried different kind of buttons. including htmlelement

Comment: Please check first if you get the same error when doing the same action with your browser. And provide a more complete sample code, at least the url you are calling....

Comment: I receive no error. @RBRi, though if you'd check you would see that the link is inside the error:  test.paypo.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FStart thank you for your interest!

Comment: Have you checked the browsers javascript console for errors?

Comment: @RBRi yes i did, no kind of error appear except one that is irrelevant.

Comment: @RBRi what I did realize tho was that no matter what kind of method I used I think that javascript isn't working properly with HTMLUnit. For example I'd get errors about referenceerror but if I called page.refresh() then no errors would appear, but the button would be clickable yet show the same page, i tried waiting and waiting for javascript and done so many different things in different ways... I noticed when debugging that webClient.waitForJavascript() always return 0, and also JavaScriptJobManager#getJobCount ALWAYS shows 0. and JavaScriptJobManager#getEarliestJob returns null too.

Comment: Any clue?.......

Answer (score 1):

Ok have done a short check with this code:

```
final String url = "https://test.paypo.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FStart";
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60)) {
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
}
```

Running this produces a bunch of errors; the first one is

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: identifier is a reserved word: class (https://test.paypo.com/bundles/SharedJS?v=qrYYsvxJCv4nRnx8xzi1sMLBQPQlIPteJjoj8eCO1go1#7)
```

What does this mean?

1. The page includes some js code from the url https://test.paypo.com/bundles/SharedJS?v=qrYYsvxJCv4nRnx8xzi1sMLBQPQlIPteJjoj8eCO1go1 and there is a problem with this code. In detail the code uses the javascript 'class' language feature and HtmlUnit (in the end Rhino) does not support this syntax in the current version
2. Because of this the javascript from this external resource is not 'compilable' and thereof not available for the other javascript on that page
3. And finally this leads to the error you are facing.

Comment: aww... would you know any alternatives?? please super important!!

Comment: maybe selenium and Firefox or chrome in headless mode

Comment: Well I've tried selenium and I really get the same error as you showed.

Comment: You have to use selenium with an real Firefox or chrome as backend

Comment: how'd i go about that?
i've got this 
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

Comment: also, that part isn't really important. i don't think i need that bundle.
moreover, when i disable javascript and then refresh page and then enable javascript, then no errors are returned but neither javascript seems to execute..

Comment: with BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER I got this error:
ption in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: missing ; before statement (https://test.paypo.com/bundles/SharedJS?v=qrYYsvxJCv4nRnx8xzi1sMLBQPQlIPteJjoj8eCO1go1#7)

The rest (firefox, chrome, edge, etc) gives me the 'class' syntax issue

Comment: anyclue? please!